# Removal of all posts content in bulk, keeping the posts itself

Tags: php, mysql

How to, using PHP scripting or WordPress overwrite all of the posts (permamently, so it takes effect on database) with some static text such as "Content removed."?

Answer (score 1):

Do not run this on a live site until you're tested it on a backup or local installation and confirmed valid results, i won't take any resposibility for lost data, should that occur.

## SQL Query

To run from PhpMyAdmin

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = 'your_content' WHERE post_type = 'post'
```

## Inside WordPress

To use inside a plugin or your functions file (run once)

```
global $wpdb;
$my_update_query = $wpdb->get_result( "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_content = 'your_content' WHERE post_type = 'post'" );
```

Comment: Might want to add a "WHERE post_type = 'post'" to avoid fudging the data in attachments and custom post types, etc. Just in case!

Comment: Yes of course, and that's exactly why i opened with saying use on a backup or test away from a live site... though i'd have hoped the user would know enough to add applicable where clauses to the query. It can't hurt to add that in though(i'll update the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you need further control of the query or the replacement function, is to use more of the WP APIs, like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => "post",
    'numberposts' => -1
    // additional arguments
    );

foreach ( get_posts( $args ) as $thispost )
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $thispost->ID,
        'post_content' => "your new content"
        )
    );
```

Bear in mind that this is much more resource-intensive than the SQL queries t31os proposed, so use with caution if you're modifying a large number of posts. See also: [How to apply content filter permanently?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3599/how-to-apply-content-filter-permanently)