# How can I globally italicize certain text?

Tags: plugins, regex

I have a large WordPress site, and I want to take a certain text phrase and italicize all instances of that phrase, for all pages.  Does anyone know of a plugin that can do this?

Particularly, for the sake of clarity, my site works like this: We have a bunch of different plant species, and of their names consist of "R.", space, and a word.  An example is *R. Sanctum*.  So I'd like to figure out how to use code to search all the pages for instances of *R. (any-text-word)*, and italicize those found instances.

I picture regex being used, but I'm eager to hear all ideas.

Comment: Please let me know if any extra clarity is needed in understanding this question.

Comment: Where would these instances exist? Just in the body of posts, or other places too? Titles? Category names?

Comment: These instances, in this case, are all within the body of pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your functions.php file. This is untested, but should work :)

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'italicize_latin_names' ); 

function italicize_latin_names( $content ) {
    // Split up the content into an array of single words
    $words = explode( ' ', $content );

    // Loop through each of those words
    foreach( $words as $key => $value ){   
        // If a word equals 'R.', add an <i> before it, and a </i> after the following word
        if($words[$key] == 'R.' ){   
            $words[$key] = '<i>' + $pieces[$key];
            $words[$key+1] = $words[$key+1] + '</i>';
        }
    }

    // Put all of the pieces back together
    return implode( '', $words );
}
```

Comment: Ah, so when the hook 'the_content' is triggered, then your custom iln function will be called.  This is cool.  I have a few questions: 1. is the variable $content already established on each page? 2. will this slow down the loading of the page, since it will perpetually run each time a page is loaded on this site 3. does the hook 'the_content' occur each time a page is loaded?

Comment: Yes that's how it works. 1) The hook for 'the_content' automatically passes in the content into the function associated with the hook. 2) PHP is very fast, so this won't be noticeable. 3) Yes that hook will run on every page load that includes <?php the_content(); ?>

Comment: Another option for you could be looping through all of your posts and running this update in the database like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3599/how-to-apply-content-filter-permanently.

Comment: One more option is just using javascript to italicize those words on page load. That way there would be ZERO delay, and it would happen so fast that your users probably wouldn't see the words without italics anyways.

Comment: I'm actually not sure which would be better. I think the DB method could get messy. I would just try the code above and see if there is any change in page load. Wordpress is already running TONS of filters on each load, so you should not notice any change at all.